# How to write batch file which use the name of one file as part of the name of another file

Tags: batch-file

I have some java executable program initialized from cmd. My problem is as following: I would like to read all files from some directory. Next, I would like to run the program as many times as many files I have in my folder. The required inputs are the path to the file with data and the name of the file where the results will be written. Now my question is, how can I write a simple batch file which will do it for me?

For example:

1. I have a list of files in my folder

   file_1.xls
   file_2.xls
   file_3.xls
2. I want to run a loop and for each file initialize line specified below:

   java -jar -Xmx1000M Program.jar pathToInputFile PathToOutputfile

For example for file file_1.xls I want to write the result to the file with the same name but different extension and at the begining of this file add some constant prefix. In case of file_1.xls the results I would like to write as Output_file_1.txt
for file_2.xls -> Output_file_2.txt
for file_3.xls -> Output_file_3.txt
and so on...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pushd "c:\excel_files"
for %%F in (*.xls) do (
  java -jar -Xmx1000M Program.jar "%%~nxF" "Output_%%~nF.txt"
)
```

Though I'll recommend you to use -classpath and direct call of the entry point class instead of direct call of the `.jar` .